# How do I remove the separators from the gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

The separators that are displayed in the gnome panel for certain themes are really ugly looking and I'd like to find out how to remove them completely (either by somehow modifying the panel separator image file, or by completely removing it).  I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and using the Radiance Theme.

Here is an example image (I split the image because it would be too wide for this page otherwise):

[image: ugly panel separators]

If someone knows how to remove these and can teach me how, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just loaded a 10.10 LiveCD and fiddled with them for a bit. It looks to me like those particular separators are hard-coded into the left-hand side of the Window List and Notification Area panel applets (I'm assuming it's to make their right-click menus easier to open without accidentally clicking one of their items instead).

I'd say that since their appearance can be changed by the theme used, you should be able to change some sort of image / other theme file for these to something completely transparent to make them go away completely. The themes are stored in `/usr/share/backgrounds`; you may want to try looking in there and see if you can find what you're looking for.

My apologies if this answer is not complete enough for you, but perhaps it might help someone else get started on an answer that can get you the rest of the way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and info.  I'll see what I can figure out while waiting to see if others reply.